# Where does Unity store the chameleonic launcher/dash color? 

Tags: unity

I would like to use unity's average background color (the color of the launcher) in conky, is there a (configuration) file which contains that color information? Or how could I fetch that?

Answer (score 2):

As I was digging around the [Dconf settings](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools) [image: Install Dconf-tools], I found this setting.

[image]

You can use this command to obtain the average background colour:

```
$ dconf read /desktop/unity/average-bg-color 
'#23d621a3050e'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, and sorry for my late answer, I've just checked today your suggestion. Anyway, your answer doesn't work for me, there were some problems with dconf, but one of unity's developers pointed out that command: xprop -root | grep _GNOME_BACKGROUND_REPRESENTATIVE_COLORS which simply works.

Comment: That looks interesting. Do you want me to update my answer with your comment now?