# How do I make the Unity launcher completely transparent?

Tags: unity, launcher, transparency

Before anyone jumps the gun and votes to close this, I am not asking how to make it "see-through", which you can adjust in CCSM by setting the Opacity to 0%.

I'm asking the following: How can you make the launcher COMPLETELY transparent?

[image]

I have both the Launcher and Top Panel set to 0%. As you can see, the Top panel is completely transparent. But, the Launcher is...well, not. Even though I set it to 0%, it is far from transparent. I'm assuming this has to do with the Chameleon coloring.

Whenever I have the Launcher on top of another window, it is transparent, but with the line on the side that separates the Launcher from the window. I did ask this in another question to see if it was possible to remove that. If anyone has an answer to remove that, let me know, but that's not quite what I had in mind.

TL,DR: I want to make it so that the Launcher is really Transparent.

Comment: @jorge-castro Thanks for the edit! For future reference, should I make my titles in question form?

Comment: Yes, as human readable as possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Incomplete answer but might be a clue):

Perhaps messing with the launcher color might make this possible?

- [Where does Unity store the chameleonic launcher/dash color?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138839/where-does-unity-store-the-chameleonic-launcher-dash-color)
- [How to change launcher opacity / transparency?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204231/how-to-change-launcher-opacity-in-ubuntu-12-10)

Comment: I've done more research and have found nothing. I'm going to accept your answer Jorge to show that this may be a lead, but for someone MUCH more experienced in Ubuntu than I am.

Answer (score 0):

You can as far as I know change the opacity of the luncher with **CompizConfig SettingsManger** (`ccsm`) if you go to *Desktop* and then to *Ubuntu Unity Plugin*. In there you go to *Experimental* and you will see *Launcher opacity*, set it to 1.

This is the most invisible i can get it. Maybe you find a better way.

---

**Edit**

I just saw that it is possible to make it completely transparent using the Unity tweak tool.

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty sure there are some png files that need changing in /usr/share/unity/themes or 6 directory.  I'm still digging around.  They definitely have some sort of basic background color to retain the hazy feel.  I want my black to be true black and my transparency to be true transparency.  Once I find the file I'll try to point it out but you should be able to open it in gimp & just delete the whole graphic so it's an empty file of the same size. I've been doing that with the launcher icon files in the /usr/share/unity/6/ folder to get the glow removed.  I'm thinking the actual launcher background is in the themes folder but I'm still checking it out.

Comment: You should never change icons in /usr/share they will be overwritten when updated. Instead please new icons in ~/.local/share (usually)