# How to change launcher opacity / transparency?

Tags: unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I change the Unity Launcher transparency?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33043/can-i-change-the-unity-launcher-transparency)

How can I change the opacity of the launcher in Ubuntu 12.10? In 12.04 I used MyUnity to do that but MyUnity is not available for Ubuntu 12.10?